# C#, .NET and IoC with Ninject: how to warm up instances of classes that take long to create?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have IOC from Ninject in my app. There are a couple classes that take significant time to initialize (some static data caches fetched from DB or files). Apparently they need to be created before handling the very first user request. Otherwise there is a high risk of timeouts. Does Ninject provide a way to tell the Kernel to go thru bindings and create some?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create those instances and pass them with WithConstructorArgument for all dependents when you wire up your app. Quite weird, I must admit, but will work.

```
var heavy = new HeavyDependency();
Bind<SomeInterface>().To<SomeClass>().WithConstructorArgument("HeavyDependency", heavy );
```

Comment: This means I construct myself, not asking Ninject to do it for me. That's what I am doing now then.

Comment: yes, exactly. It's not elegant and I try to avoid when it's possible, but it's very handly for some situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the dependency behind a proxy and load it in the background:

```
public class LazyHeavyDependency : IHeavyDependency 
{
    private readonly Lazy<IHeavyDependency> lazy;

    public LazyHeavyDependency(Lazy<IHeavyDependency> lazy)
    {
        this.lazy = lazy;
    }

    void IHeavyDependency.DoWork()
    {
        this.lazy.Value.DoWork();
    }
}
```

You can wire it up like this:

```
var lazyDependency = new Lazy<IHeavyDependency>(() =>
    new RealHeavyDependency());

Bind<IHeavyDependency>()
    .ToConstant(new LazyHeavyDependency(lazyDependency));

// Load value in a background thread.
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => lazy.Value);
```